# Using javap for reading the byte code

Tags: java, javac, javap

I figured out by reading in the internet that java compiles

```
public class Test {
    private String s = "TESTTEST";
}
```

to

```
public class Test {
    private String s;

    public Test() {
        s = "TESTTEST";
    }
}
```

Am I right?

Now I tried to comprehend this by myself. So I compile the class `Test.java` by invoking

```
javac Test.java
```

After it, I've read that I can use `javap` to read the compiled code (=byte code).

So I've tried to see the restructuring from the compiler in the byte code, which I mentioned above (that the decleration is IN the constructor). But how?? Is `javap` the right tool for that? If yes, with which parameters?

Thanks for your help!

edit:

Ok, thanks so far! Can you explain me please how to read the output of `javap -c Test`?

```
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop>javap -c Test
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: ldc           #2                  // String TESTTEST
       7: putfield      #3                  // Field s:Ljava/lang/String;
      10: return
}
```

Comment: The only thing I see in your output is the constructor. `public Test()` is what it's called, just like it's called in your source file. So you don't need to look far, it's right in front of you. Or am I not understanding what you're looking for?

Comment: What change do you expect there to be? The two forms are equivalent.

Comment: Maybe you could edit into your question an explanation of what *you* think your `javap` output means, and why? It looks to me like your second code block, and if I'm understanding you, that's what you were expecting to find. So I'm not sure why you feel you didn't find it.

Comment: Thank you for your hints! I've changed the question a little bit!

Comment: Hmm. The thing is, now your question's answer is "yes, that's the right tool, with the parameters you used before, because it gives the output you just removed from your question"

Comment: Try `javap -c Test`  or just: `javap -help`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your field is `private`, you also need to give the `-p` argument to see private members. To see what happens with multiple constructors, I added an extra one.

```java
class Test {
    private String s = "TESTTEST";
    Test() {
    }
    Test(int x) {
    }
}
```

```
javap -c -p Test.class
```

```java
class Test {
  private java.lang.String s;

  Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: ldc           #12                 // String TESTTEST
       7: putfield      #14                 // Field s:Ljava/lang/String;
      10: return

  Test(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: ldc           #12                 // String TESTTEST
       7: putfield      #14                 // Field s:Ljava/lang/String;
      10: return
}
```

In both constructors, this is basically:

```java
<constructor> {
    super();              // Instructions: 0, 1
    this.s = "TESTTEST";  // Instructions: 4, 5, 7
    return;               // Instructions: 10
}
```

Teaching you bytecode is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. See [The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html) for full list of bytecode instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The advent of [jclasslib Bytecode viewer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9248-jclasslib-bytecode-viewer/) brings the challenge and opportunity for you.